# Trying to add a reference to my solution

Tags: c#, wpf, reference

I am a complete stranger to adding "custom" references to my projects, usually everything I need I can find in NuGet packages. Ive come across a problem and the solution I've found is to add the following reference to my project:

https://microsoftdwayneneed.codeplex.com/

Ive downloaded the source code, opened up the project in VS and hit build. I then went into the bin/Release folder and added the .dll for both Win32 and normal which I assume is any CPU.

The problem I faced earlier is now fixed, however now a new problem arised: I keep getting the message that the Microsoft Visual Studio XAML UI Designer has stopped working. The error it gives is a NullReferenceException and in the name is "dwayneneed" so I can only assume that I messed up adding the reference.

Can someone explain to me how to add references like the one above correctly to my solution.

The problem Im trying to solve for those wondering:
https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/488

the solution, see: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean adding a solution to the solution, like this. [image]

Comment: Yes this is how I added the .dll to my solution. This caused the WPF problem I had to be fixed however now my Designer in VS is not loading at all anymore, when I try to reload it it crashes.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry I didn't understand. In that case, I doubt there should be a problem with adding the reference. Apart from that I don't fully know.